# Web application becomes slow after executing stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a web application in which I am showing a report by executing a stored procedure. Execution takes too long time but after showing report that means after finishing execution of stored procedure, app becomes very slow. Just even if I navigate to some other page it takes quite a long time.

Is it possible after executing stored procedure, still something is going on behind. Still stored procedure is running or tables are locked or something like this. How to find out the reason.

My server is SQL server 2008R2.

Comment: what does your stored procedure look like?

Comment: Does it happen when you are stepping through it in the debugger?

Comment: you can try running sp_who on db to see if there are any blocking queries, but other than that, there's not enough details for us to do anything but guess (execution plan cached poorly, or some other reason)

Comment: Google it [c# how to performance troubleshoot](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+how+to+performance+troubleshoot). That is not meant to be rude but there is no way we can help you with the limited information you have given. You, or someone with direct access to your code and environment,  will have to do the leg work yourself. You need to start by isolating the problem, start at the macro level and then narrow it down from there. By macro I mean is it your c# code or is it the database server. Maybe the db is slow because of ??? which causes the app's calls to the db to be slow.. good luck

Answer (score 0):

You might need to run few diagnostics , i would rather follow a stepwise approach

1) Check for any blocking processes

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.sysprocesses WHERE blocked <> 0;
SELECT * FROM dbo.sysprocesses WHERE spid IN (SELECT blocked FROM dbo.sysprocesses where blocked <> 0)
```

2) Check for any slow running queries

```
SELECT r.session_id
    ,s.TEXT
    ,r.[status]
    ,r.blocking_session_id
    ,r.cpu_time
    ,r.total_elapsed_time
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests r
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS s
```

3) run `cmd` in windows and check for webservices status

```
   sc query <servicename>
```